# user_passes_test for CreateView class in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to use user_passes_test for the group Rep to this class.How can I apply this to a create view.

> @user_passes_test(lambda u: u.groups.filter(name='hod').exists())

views.py

```
class RetestCreate(CreateView):
    model = Retest
    fields = ['semester', 'dept', 'batch', 'date', 'subject', 'name', 'admnno', 'reason', 'proof', 'is_sure']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use any function view decorator on a method with [method_decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class). `user_passes_test` can be used on `.dispatch` method, this way it will work for every request method:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

class RetestCreate(CreateView):
    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Since django 1.9, method_decorator could be used to decorate class  and pass the name of the method to be decorated as the keyword argument name:  @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser), name='dispatch')